# Is it possible to add extra parameters to the before() method for the policies?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 10.

I have a policy in which I would like to always return true in a particular case.

So I decided to write this specific case in the before [method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#policy-filters) instead of repeating the condition in each other method (viewing, view, etc...)

In a native policy, the before method is like that :

```
public function before(User $user): bool|null
```

In my case, I would like to add an extra parameter to this method, like that :

```
public function before(User $user, School $school): bool|null
```

Of course, it does not work! So How to add this extra parameter?

Comment: curious question, is `$user` related to `$school` in any way?

Comment: Yes , an user belongs to 1 school. Why ?

Comment: Though it doesn't seem documented I think you might be able to do `before(User $user, string $abilityName, ?School $school)`

Answer (score 0):

The extra parameter must go after the string $ability, like this:

```
public function before(User $user, string $ability, School $school): bool|null
{
    //
}
```